# How will a static delegate access non-static, server-side, session-based information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, data-access-layer

Sorry about the title. This is fairly complex. I'll try to summarise it in a simplified, abstract way (as much as I can).

In a web forms application, the DAL will be used from two different contexts:

1. From code-behind
2. From a Web API controller

In each call, the DAL needs to be made aware of the current User Id so that it can store this id against database transactions. I've added a static property to the DAL that is of type Func, such that when the DAL is used, it can be provided with a method (by the callng code) that allows it to fetch the user id.

The calls made from code-behind would provide a GetUserId method that get the user id from session, whereas the Web API controller calls (which are stateless) will have the user id as a parameter and will be able to return that value.

What concerns me is that statics in a web environment are shared across sessions. So..

1. When user A runs a session that sets the GetUserId method to return the Session["UserId"], and user B runs a session that does the same thing at the same time, will each transaction receive the correct user id? I'm thinking that because HttpContext.Current is a static itself, this should be okay.
2. When user A makes a call through the Web API controller and sets the GetUserId method to return the parameter value (let's say id 1), and then user B makes the same call at the same time, but the user id parameter is 2... will one replace the other, or will they remain distinct? I'm thinking that they're probably going to clash.

If they're going to clash, then I'll find another way to do it, but I wanted to avoid having to pass the user id into every object Save().

**SOLUTION**

Prompted by Steven's answer, I've had a play CallContext just to prove to myself that it will retain context against a specific thread, in spite of being called through a static. Following is a **very** simple test with overlapping threads. Next I'll try it in a Web API environment, which should be the same.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            StartTestThread(i);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void StartTestThread(int i)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Setting context...", i));
            SetCallContext(i);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Waiting...", i));
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] Context is {1}", i, GetCallContext()));
        });
    }

    private static void SetCallContext(int i)
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("Test", i);
    }

    private static int GetCallContext()
    {
        return (int) CallContext.LogicalGetData("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should side-step the issue altogether and pass in a value to your DAL constructor or method calls. I see what you are trying to achieve, I just don't think it's worth it.

Comment: btw: HttpContext.Current is populated per-request by the `Global.asax`, session as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from `HttpContext.Current.Session` is obviously safe, since `HttpContext.Current` returns a different `HttpContext` instance for each request. But since your `Func` field is static, replacing the `Func` will of course make your code fail misserably, since there is just one instance of a static field per App Domain. So you should take a different approach.

For instance, instead of replacing the Func, initialize it just once and let it handle the Web API case as well. For instance:

```
GetUserId = () =>
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    // MVC / Web Forms
    if (context.Session != null && context.Session["UserId"] != null) {
        return (int)context.Session["UserId"];
    }

    // Web API
    return (int)CallContext.LogicalGetData("__userId");
};

public static void RegisterWebApiUserId(int userId) {
    CallContext.LogicalSetData("__userId", userId);
}
```

Comment: So each user session has its own GUID key in CallContext, which leads to the user's id. But how would the DAL object get hold of that GUID? I've not used CallContext before, so forgive me for being slow.

Or is it simply that each instantiation of the DAL generates a key for that instance, and then the static method.. hang on.. the static method won't be able to see the non-static key, will it?

Comment: @MattWinward: No, you generate the key once in the app domain. I updated my question to made this more obvious.

Comment: Ah okay. So the key can just be a static value ("__userId" in the example), and CallContext stores a value per 'call', effectively providing the same functionality as Session, but for the Web API calls?

Comment: @MattWinward: The 'call' will have the lifetime of a single Web API request, flows with asynchronous method calls and even, flows with parallel tasks that are spans from the request.

Comment: Thanks. This is brilliant. I'll give it a whirl and see what happens!

Comment: @MattWinward: What you're basically doing here is Dependency Inversion. You might have even better results when using Dependency *Injection* and inject an `IUserContext` interface into the constructors of your DAL classes. This however might be a significant architectural shift.

Comment: In some ways, that's actually not a bad idea. If I used a dependency injection library, like ninject, I could presumably have it automatically provide some object to the DAL classes that require the information, and that object could carry with it the current user details.. maybe. I'll give it some thought. I'll have a play with CallContext first though.

Comment: @MattWinward: Here's another idea: Use [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) instead of Ninject :-P

Comment: If I use Simple Injector, which then provides a UserContext object to the DAL object when its instantiated within a Web API call, I'm assuming the object won't have access to session?

Comment: @MattWinward: During a Web Api request, there might not always be a `HttpContext.Current`, so yes, you won't have access to the session. You can have two `IUserContext` implementations; an `IWebApiUserContext` and a `MvcUserContext` implementation. But to be honest, [I think it is better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12651630/264697) to place Web API stuf in its own project.