# SimpleInjector Request Scope from Service layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a multi-tier application where my implementation of my `DbContext` and `UnitOfWork` is lying in my service layer. This layer does not have a reference to `System.Web`.

Together with the implementations lies my `CompositionRoot` class which is referred from my UI layer, using extensions, to initialize all my injections.

But my `DbContext` and `UnitOfWork` requires a request scope, and I am not able to set this like the example below, since I do not have access to `HttpContext` or `WebRequestLifestyle`.

**Should I move this `RegisterEntityFramework(...)` extension to my UI layer in order to use request scope, or should I just reference the System.Web in my service layer - or another approach?**

I am new to Dependency Injection so maybe I just being too paranoid about what the best practices are in such senario.

*ServiceLayer/EntityFramework/CompositionRoot.cs*

```
public static class CompositionRoot
{
    public static void RegisterEntityFramework(this Container container)
    {
        var lifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
            lifestyleSelector: () => HttpContext.Current != null, // HttpContext not available
            trueLifestyle: new WebRequestLifestyle(),
            falseLifestyle: new LifetimeScopeLifestyle()
        );

        var contextRegistration = lifestyle.CreateRegistration<EntityDbContext, EntityDbContext>(container);
        container.AddRegistration(typeof(EntityDbContext), contextRegistration);
        container.AddRegistration(typeof(IUnitOfWork), contextRegistration);
    }
}
```

*UILayer/App_Start/CompositionRoot.cs*

```
public static class RootComposition
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.RegisterEntityFramework(); // extension

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider();

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) is part of the startup path of the application. In your case that's your web application. The Composition Root [references all assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application) in the system. The only reason to move business layer specific registrations out of this part is when the business layer is reused by multiple end applications (both an MVC application and a WCF web service for instance).

If you move everything to your web application, the registration of your DbContext will be simple:

```
var scopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
var contextRegistration =
    scopedLifestyle.CreateRegistration<EntityDbContext, EntityDbContext>(container);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(EntityDbContext), contextRegistration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IUnitOfWork), contextRegistration);
```

If you have multiple applications and need to reuse the registration logic of the business layer, you don't know exactly what lifestyle to use. In that case you can supply the business layer composition root with the `ScopedLifestyle`:

```
public static void RegisterEntityFramework(this Container container, 
    ScopedLifestyle lifestyle)
{
    var contextRegistration =
        lifestyle.CreateRegistration<EntityDbContext, EntityDbContext>(container);
    container.AddRegistration(typeof(EntityDbContext), contextRegistration);
    container.AddRegistration(typeof(IUnitOfWork), contextRegistration);
}
```

You can call this from within your Application_Start as follows:

```
container.RegisterEntityFramework(new WebRequestLifestyle());
```

Comment: You are the king, this is smart!

Comment: As a side question: You would wire everything up in my /App_Start/CompositionRoot.cs and not have separate "modules" in my business layer?

Comment: @meep: IMO You should only have such 'module' in the business layer if you have multiple end applications.

Comment: Since this is a web mvc app with an web api - i might just move it to the main composition  root :-) Thanks again!

Comment: @meep: IMO you should usually [separate MVC and Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12651630/264697) (give them their own project). When you do that, that means you have to move the shared part to a different place. That would be either the business layer or some sort of `BusinessLayer.Bootstrap` assembly.

Comment: Great stuff, I will do that - thanks! :-) I will keep my existing setup with a bit of modification and separate MVC/API